# Implementing Difference-In-Differences Estimator with GLM in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to implement a [difference-in-differences estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences#Implementation) with a GLM model with Stata 13.0. The parameter I am interested in is the derivative of the expected value with respect to the interaction of binary treatment group indicator T and binary post-treatment period indicator S *only* (T#S, rather than the full derivative with respect to T). This approach is explained towards the end of [this thread](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-01/msg00293.html) on Statalist. This is my code:

```
glm y i.T##i.S, exposure(e) cluster(user_id) link(log) family(poisson) robust
preserve
    replace e = 30
    margins rb0.T#rb0.S
restore
```

The preserve/replace/restore step is necessary because margins does not allow the `at()` option to be used with exposure variables.

Two questions.

1. How would I get a p-value for this effect?
2. Is it possible to get the effect in semi-elasticity form, perhaps by using margins with eydx() in some way?